# How I can find my program has access to cameras

Tags: windows, delphi, camera

How can I find out if my program has access to cameras?

I use `TdxCameraControl` by Dev Express in Delphi 10.1 and Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings on your pc
Privacy & Security -> Category( App Permissions) **Camera** -> second section
( let apps access your camera ) See your app and turn on/off

Comment: I know what you are telling me.

Comment: But I wish to know programmatically that i wish to tell exact same thing to the user.